# Getting TTR to work on R 2.13?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages)

Has anyone gotten the [latest version of TTR from R-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/ttr) working on R 2.13? I can't install it on either my mac or my PC, even if I try compiling from the source.

/edit: here's the exact error I'm getting, when I try to install from the R command line.

```
install.packages("TTR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘TTR’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
```

Comment: Did you try `install.packages("TTR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")`?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: yes, and I get the same error.  Dirk's answer worked for me on my mac, but I still can't get it to install on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
edd@max:~/svn/ttr$ svn up
At revision 107.
edd@max:~/svn/ttr$ R CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘TTR’ ...
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/TTR/libs
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
Loading required package: zoo
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (TTR)
```

and

```
edd@max:~/svn/ttr$ R -e 'library(TTR); example(EMA)'

R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]
R> library(TTR); example(EMA)
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: zoo

EMAR>   data(ttrc)

EMAR>     ema.20 <-   EMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 20)

EMAR>     sma.20 <-   SMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 20)

EMAR>    dema.20 <-  DEMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 20)

EMAR>   evwma.20 <- EVWMA(ttrc[,"Close"], ttrc[,"Volume"], 20)

EMAR>   zlema.20 <- ZLEMA(ttrc[,"Close"], 20)

EMAR>   ## Example of Tim Tillson's T3 indicator
EMAR>   T3 <- function(x, n=10, v=1) DEMA(DEMA(DEMA(x,n,v),n,v),n,v)

EMAR>   t3 <- T3(ttrc[,"Close"])

EMAR>   ## Example of short-term instability of EMA
EMAR>   ## (and other indicators mentioned above)
EMAR>   x <- rnorm(100)

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[90:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.192859

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[70:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.149217

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[50:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.153751

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[30:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.153703

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[10:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.153703

EMAR>   tail( EMA(x[ 1:100],10), 1 )
[1] 0.153703
R>
```

Answer (score 0):

The News says it's now on CRAN. My Mac has 0.20-2 on it and the installer reports that to be the most recent. Loading seems to succeed and no errors from running a few examples.

Re the r-forge version 20-3 I get this:

> install.packages("TTR", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
>   Warning message:
>   In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
>     package ‘TTR’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0 beta)

R version 2.13.0 beta (2011-04-04 r55296) (not the latest)

Comment: The version on r-forge is 0.20-3, which is slightly newer.

Comment: Right. But if it's "not available" is there any reason you can't do with 0.20-2?

Comment: It has an additional indicator (DVI) that I wish to use.