# Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages

Tags: r, svn, installation, package, r-forge

[This](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/10265), [question](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/10022), [is](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/9715), [asked](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/9359), [over](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/9169/focus=9170), [and](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/9135), [over](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/8645), [and](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/7965), [over](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.finance/7173), 
on the [R-sig-finance](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-finance) mailing list, but I do not think it has been asked on stackoverflow.

It goes like this:

Where can I obtain the latest version of package XYZ that is hosted on R-forge?  I tried to install it with `install.packages`, but this is what happened:

```
> install.packages("XYZ",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
Warning message: package ‘XYZ’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)
```

Looking on the R-forge website for XYZ, I see that the package failed to build.
Therefore, there is no link to download the source.  Is there any other way 
to get the source code?  Once I get the source code, how can I turn that into a 
package that I can load with `library("XYZ")`?

Comment: THANK YOU, @GSee. S.O. is much easier to search and I knew it must have been asked a zillion times.

Comment: Windows users should additionally read this: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset

Answer (score 54, accepted):

R-Forge may fail to build a package for a few different reasons.  It could be that
the documentation has not been updated to reflect recent changes in the code.  Or,
it could be that some of the dependencies were not available at build time.

You can checkout the source code using svn.  First, search for the project on the
R-Forge website and go to the project home page -- for example http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/returnanalytics/
Click the SCM link to get to a page like this  http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=579

This page will tell you the command to use to checkout the project.  In this case you get

> This project's SVN repository can be checked out through anonymous access with the following command(s).
>
> svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/returnanalytics/

If you are on Windows, you probably want to download and install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/)

Once you have installed TortoiseSVN, you can right click in a Windows Explorer window and select
"SVN checkout".  In the "URL of repository:" field, enter everything except the
"svn checkout " part of the command that you found on R-Forge.  In this case, you'd
enter "svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/returnanalytics/".

When you click OK, the project will be downloaded into the current directory.

If you are on a UNIX-alike system (or if you installed the command line client tools
when you installed TortoiseSVN for Windows, which is not the default), you can
type the command that R-forge gave you in your terminal (System terminal, not the R terminal)

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/returnanalytics/
```

That will create a new directory under the current working directory that
contains all of the files in the package.  In the top level of that directory
will be a subdirectory called "pkg".  This particular project (returnanalytics)
contains more than one package.

```
ls returnanalytics/pkg
#FactorAnalytics  MPO  PApages  PerformanceAnalytics  PortfolioAnalytics
```

But some R-forge projects only have a single package. e.g.

```
svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/random/
#Checked out revision 14.
ls random/pkg
#DESCRIPTION  inst  man  NAMESPACE  R
```

Now that you have a local copy all of the code, if you would like to be able to
install the package, you have to build it first.

A WORD OF CAUTION:  Since R-Forge failed to build the package, there is a good chance
that there are problems with the package.  Therefore, if you just build it, you may find
that some things do not work as expected.  In particular, it is likely that there
is missing or incomplete documentation.

If you are on a UNIX-alike system, the package can be built and installed relatively easily.  For a multi-package project like returnanalytics, if you want to install, e.g. the
PortfolioAnalytics package, you can do it like this

```
R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build returnanalytics/pkg/PortfolioAnalytics
```

"PortfolioAnalytics" is the name of the directory that contains the package that
you want to build/install.  For a single-package project, you can build and install like
this

```
R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build random/pkg
```

If you would like to build/install a package on Windows, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739837/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-the-source-tarball-on-windows) and follow the [two](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Windows-packages) [links](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) that @JoshuaUlrich provided

More information can be found in [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Add_002don-packages), [the R-Forge User Manual](http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/R-Forge_Manual.pdf), and [the SVN manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).

Comment: The use of `--vanilla` is probably not necessary depending on what is in .Rprofile.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639336/

Comment: `INSTALL --build` builds a binary version of the package, but does not install it.  Also, it'd be easier to do `install.packages("XYZ",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org", type = "source")`

Comment: @hadley R CMD build builds a package without installing it. R CMD INSTALL --build _does_ install it; try for yourself. As for `install.packages(..., repos="http://r-forge...", type="source")`, perhaps you should read the question again.

Comment: Wow, it does. The documentation is very unclear! (I don't see an option to build an binary package with `R CMD build`) And why do you need `--build` for this answer?  I also don't see why `install.packages + type = "source"` is worse than an svn checkout + `R CMD install`

Comment: svn checkout + `install.packages` with `repos=NULL` is fine, but since we're already on the command line for the `svn checkout` part, I just installed it from there.  That is a really good question about `--build`.  I thought that `R CMD INSTALL --build myPackage` was equivalent to `R CMD build myPackage` followed by `R CMD INSTALL myPackage_1.0.tar.gz`.  However, after some testing, I see that they are not the same -- `.Rbuildignore` does not seem to be honored with `R CMD INSTALL --build myPackage`.

Comment: @hadley Regarding no option to build a binary with R CMD build, R NEWS from 2.14.0 has an entry that says "R CMD build --binary is now formally deprecated: R CMD INSTALL --build has long been the preferred alternative."

Comment: I _think_ `R CMD install --build` installs the package, and then makes a compressed copy - which causes a bug in devtools (https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/335) so I'm glad I commented here!

Comment: HTTP is deprecated for all GitHub requests and are 301 redirected to HTTPS equivalents. Some libraries don't handle that well, so trying an HTTPS eqivalent may be helpful in diagnosing this as I did with a `curl -i` over in [another SO question about GitHub and R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740256/error-installing-packages-from-github/18436125#18436125)

Comment: @GSee, I ran the code `R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build returnanalytics/pkg/PerformanceAnalytics/` , but error occurs:

> * installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library’

> * installing *source* package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ ...
> ** libs
> gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  momentF.f90 -o momentF.o
> make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
> make: *** [momentF.o] Error 1
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’

How could I correct it? Thanks

Comment: @Kenny Not sure, but I think you need to install tools: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

Answer (score 3):

If (and only if) you have the appropriate toolchain for your OS, then this may succeed:

```
# First download source file to your working directory
# As an example use browser to download pkg:partykit from: 
#  http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/src/contrib/partykit_1.1-2.tar.gz
# Move to working directory
# Or in the case of returnanalytics (which is a bundle of packages):
# http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=579 and download the tar.gz (source)
# Then in R:

install.packages( "partykit_1.1-2.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
# for the first of the ReturnAnalytics packages:
install.packages( "Dowd_0.11.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
```

These direction should be "cross-platform". <strike>I'm not sure the directions in the accepted answer are applicable to Macs (OSX)</strike>. (I later confirmed that they do "work" on a Mac but found the process more involved that what I suggested above. They do result in a directory that do contain the packages in a form that should succeed with `R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build pathToEachPackageSeparately`)

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible that the current version of the package you are trying to install requires a newer version of R, for example, you may see error like:

"ERROR: this R is version 2.15.0, package 'PerformanceAnalytics' requires R >= 3.0.0"

then you can try to update your R

or, if you are facing the same situation with me, which is trying to use pqR (currently using R version 2.15), you can find the out-of-date achieved package here:

http://cran.at.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/PerformanceAnalytics/

You can get here from R-Forge packages page -> "Stable Release: Get PerformanceAnalytics 1.4.3541 from CRAN" -> Old sources:    PerformanceAnalytics archive

for example, you will find package PerformanceAnalytics version 1.1.0 just requires R >= 2.14

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can install the particular package from GitHub, if it has a repo at GitHub.

I ran `install.packages('ggfortify')`, and got

> Warning message: “package ‘ggfortify’ is not available (for R version
>   3.3.2)”

[ggfortify](https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify) was the GitHub repo for the same package.

The [`devtools`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) library allows you to install a package from GitHub directly with `install_github('username/repo')`.

```
library(devtools)
install_github('sinhrks/ggfortify')
```