# adding Fees to the addTxns() function for R in blotter or quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

Hi I am looking at the addTxns function in blotter, and I would like to add fees data/information in the TxnData argument (as a column).

When looking at the function, by running

```
blotter:::addTxns
```

it seems to use the column names "Price" and "Quantity" but automatically sets/assigns the TxnFees to zero.

Is there a way of overwriting this, so that it can be included in my analysis?

Here is an example:

```
rm(list=ls(pos=.blotter),pos=.blotter)
rm(list=ls(pos=.instrument),pos=.instrument)
rm(list=ls(pos=.strategy),pos=.strategy)

currency('USD')
stock("SPY", currency="USD", mulitplier=1)

getSymbols('SPY', from='2012-03-01', to='2012-07-04')

portf.name <- "dummy.Portfolio"  

initPortf(portf.name, 'SPY', initDate='2012-02-29')
initAcct(portf.name, portf.name, initDate='2012-02-29', initEq=1e6)

qty <- rep(c(1,-1), nrow(SPY)/2)
price <- SPY[,4]
txnfees <- rep(-5, nrow(SPY))
txndata <- cbind(qty, price, txnfees)
colnames(txndata) <- c("Quantity","Price","txnfees")

blotter:::addTxns(Portfolio=portf.name, Symbol='SPY', TxnData=txndata )

txns <- getTxns(Portfolio=portf.name, Symbol='SPY')

head(txns)
```

This will show the buying and selling of 1 share on alternate days at the close but will not show any of the fees relating to each transaction.

Comment: You should really this on the r-sig-finance list.  Add check its archives as it covers _a lot_ of blotter / quantstrat questions.

Comment: Haven't see this hit the r-sig-finance list yet, but you're going to need to come up with a reproducible example.  Have you read `?addTxns`? `TxnFees` _can_ be a function of `TxnQty` and `TxnPrice`, but it can also just be a negative number (positive for rebates).  `txnfees` (note the case) is only set to zero if it is `NULL` or `NA`

Comment: An example has been added which should hopefully be reproducible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Patched in Rev. 1100.](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=316)

After [checking out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages), building and installing the new code, I believe this will do what you want:

```
library(blotter)
currency('USD')
stock("SPY", currency="USD", mulitplier=1)
getSymbols('SPY', from='2012-03-01', to='2012-07-04')
portf.name <- "dummy.Portfolio"
initPortf(portf.name, 'SPY', initDate='2012-02-29')
initAcct(portf.name, portf.name, initDate='2012-02-29', initEq=1e6)
qty <- rep(c(1,-1), nrow(SPY)/2)
price <- SPY[,4]
txnfees <- rep(-5, nrow(SPY))
txndata <- cbind(qty, price, txnfees)
colnames(txndata) <- c("Quantity","Price","TxnFees")
blotter:::addTxns(Portfolio=portf.name, Symbol='SPY', TxnData=txndata )
txns <- getTxns(Portfolio=portf.name, Symbol='SPY')
head(txns)
```

(Here is [link to our discussion on r-sig-finance](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2012q3/010494.html))