# XTS to.weekly returns different weekly endpoints

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have a problem where the `endpoints()` function in `xts` (and also the `to.weekly` function, which uses endpoints) sometimes returns Friday as the end of week, and sometimes returns Monday.

My dataset is called `sp2`.

```
> head(sp2)
           [,1]
2012-01-09 1.78
2012-01-10 1.78
2012-01-11 1.77
2012-01-12 1.80
2012-01-13 1.77
2012-01-16 1.77

> tail(sp2)
           [,1]
2012-06-28 1.94
2012-06-29 1.92
2012-07-02 1.92
2012-07-03 1.90
2012-07-04 1.89
2012-07-05 1.89

> class(sp2)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> weekdays(index(sp2))
  [1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [11] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [21] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [31] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [41] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [51] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [61] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [71] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [81] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
 [91] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[101] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[111] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"   
[121] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"
```

So as you can see there are no missing weekdays in the data series.

Yet.....

```
> weekdays(index(to.weekly(sp2)))
 [1] "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Friday"   "Monday"  
[12] "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"  
[23] "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Thursday"
```

Surely this should always be Friday (except for the last point which is today, Thursday)?

What am I doing wrong here, and is there a workaround?

I wish to compute weekly changes on this data series from Friday to Friday.

..........................................REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE ........................

```
i <- as.Date((as.numeric(Sys.Date())-200):as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
x <- xts(rep(1, length(i)), order.by = i)
weekdays(index(to.weekly(x)))
#  [1] "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"  
# [14] "Sunday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"  
# [27] "Monday"   "Monday"   "Monday"   "Thursday"
y <- xts(rep(1, length(i)), order.by = as.POSIXct(i))
weekdays(index(to.weekly(y)))
# [1] "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"  
# [14] "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"  
# [27] "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Sunday"   "Thursday"
```

Comment: What version of xts are you using?

Comment: I just upgraded to R2.15.1 and ran an update.packages(). Shows "0.8-2".

Comment: Oops - I see we are at 0.8-6. 
Update (y/N/c)?  y
Warning: packages ‘xts’, ‘zoo’ are in use and will not be installed

That's probably the problem. Let me fix it....

Comment: If the problem persists after updating, can you please make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I found the solution. It is that my date index data (coming from Bloomberg) was in "Date" format. Changing this to POSIXct solves the problem.

Comment: That shouldn't matter... can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: I have modified it slightly to produce an easily reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the CRAN version that has been fixed on R-Forge.  Basically, the time component of the index wasn't being dropped and you ran into some funky business with timezones and daylight saving time.

[Install from R-Forge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11105131/271616) to use the corrected function.

```
require(xts)
i <- Sys.Date()+200:0
x <- xts(rep(1, length(i)), order.by = i)
y <- xts(rep(1, length(i)), order.by = as.POSIXct(i))
all.equal(weekdays(index(to.weekly(x))), weekdays(index(to.weekly(y))))
```