# Using --vanilla with R CMD build

Tags: r, package

According to the document *Writing R Extensions* [ss 1.3](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages) "R CMD check and R CMD build run R with --vanilla, so none of the user's startup files are read".

This doesn't seem to happen  on my installation. I have found that my version of R (2.15.1 on Mac) loads the packages in my `.Rprofile` - i am pretty sure about this, as i've managed to reliably break it by adding `library(hobblegobble)` to my `.Rprofile`.

does this matter? If so, should i *always* prefer to build packages with

```
R --vanilla CMD build
```

thanks

Comment: I rolled my learning experience, including this SO reply, into a [blog](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2012/07/28/creating-an-r-package-in-10-mins/). Thanks v much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `R --vanilla CMD build myPackage` or `R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build myPackage` if your .Rprofile loads packages that you are trying to build (or install).

The only drawback I am aware of to using `--vanilla` is that the terminal's completion (i.e. having the package directory name completed for you when you tap <kbd>tab</kbd>) may not work while you're typing the path to the package directory.

However, a better solution may be to wrap `if (interactive()) {}` around code in your .Rprofile that you only want to be run in interactive sessions. e.g. `library` or `require` calls.

In your case if your .Rprofile had `if (interactive()) library(hobblegobble)` you wouldn't need to use `--vanilla`.

Comment: thanks - this is my first package, so i'm totally in the dark. I have also run into the problem that `R CMD build` fails as my `.Rprofile` is trying to load the very package i'm trying to re-build. That's what made me think that `--vanilla` may be the appropriate way to do this.

Comment: It's interesting that _Writing R Extensions_ says you shouldn't have to use `--vanilla`; like you, that has not been my experience.

Comment: @ricardo, in your .Rprofile, use `if (interactive()) library(hobblegobble)`.  That way `R CMD build` will not load it.  Thanks to Dirk for the suggestion in [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5056884#5056884)