# No applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"

Tags: r, xts, zoo

Please, put this data structure into R in order to reproduce my example:

```
dX <- structure(c(3272.1, 3271.48, 3281.03, 3267.08, 3260.65, NA, 1616.3, 
1620.1, 1639.9, 1637.4, 1669.6, 1662.2, 528.385, 529.268, 531.022, 
532.424, NA, NA), .indexTZ = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", index = structure(c(1345147200, 
1345406400, 1345492800, 1345579200, 1345665600, 1345752000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("M1WO.Index", 
"GC1.COMB.Comdty", "JGAGGUSD.Index")))
```

Now try this code:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
library(timeSeries)
charts.PerformanceSummary(R = dX)
```

and get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("time<-") :
  no applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"
```

I guess the issue is about the datas whose `class = c("xts, "zoo")`, but I do not understand why it reads those datas in that format and how may I coerce it to a simple `xts` object.

How could I solve this issue?

My system:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] timeSeries_2160.94           timeDate_2160.95            
 [3] quantmod_0.3-17              TTR_0.21-1                  
 [5] Defaults_1.1-1               PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4
 [7] xts_0.8-6                    zoo_1.7-7                   
 [9] rcom_2.2-5                   rscproxy_2.0-5              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] fBasics_2160.81  fGarch_2110.80.1 grid_2.15.1      lattice_0.20-6  
[5] MASS_7.3-18      stabledist_0.6-4 tools_2.15.1
```

When I load packages, I get the following:

```
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: timeDate

Attaching package: ‘timeDate’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:PerformanceAnalytics’:

    kurtosis, skewness

Attaching package: ‘timeSeries’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:zoo’:

    time<-
```

According to the error messagge, I guess the issue comes when attaching `timeSeries` and `time<-` is masked from `package:zoo`, which I do not really know what it does mean and how to deal with.

Comment: Have you loaded the package `xts` ?

Comment: Of course I have :)

I've just added another command line to my example code, in order to load `quantmod` and so load `xts` as well.

Comment: Consider that `class(as.xts(dX))` still returns an `"xts"  "zoo"` object, while I would like to omit the `zoo` component.

Comment: I don't get an error with your code. What is the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: It's too long to be attached here. What's the field you're interested in? 

`R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252`

Comment: `attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] timeSeries_2160.94           timeDate_2160.95            
 [3] quantmod_0.3-17              TTR_0.21-1                  
 [5] Defaults_1.1-1               PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4
 [7] xts_0.8-6                    zoo_1.7-7                   
 [9] rcom_2.2-5                   rscproxy_2.0-5    `

Comment: `loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] fBasics_2160.81  fGarch_2110.80.1 grid_2.15.1      lattice_0.20-6  
[5] MASS_7.3-18      stabledist_0.6-4 tools_2.15.1  `

Comment: You can add it as an edit to your question. I see you have loaded some packages that are not loaded by your code. Do you get the error, if you run your code in a new R session? Did you get a warning that functions were masked, when loading packages (e.g. timeSeries_2160.94)?

Comment: I get the same error in a new session. I follow your suggestment and edit my question to show you what's masked when I load packages. Just a moment...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is package `timeSeries`. Loading it gives the following warning:

```
Attaching package: ‘timeSeries’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:zoo’:

    time<-
```

You can detach the package for using `charts.PerformanceSummary` and than load it again:

```
detach('package:timeSeries')
detach('package:timeDate') # since it masks statistical functions
charts.PerformanceSummary(R = dX)
library(timeSeries)
```

Comment: Thank you, Roland. Please, assume I **have to** load `timeSeries`: how may I deal with this problem?

Comment: Yep! What else? :)
Thank you very much

Comment: @user1621969, You can patch your version of PerformanceAnalytics.  Change line 237 of chart.TimeSeries.R to `rownames = as.Date(xts:::time.xts(y))`.  Then, rebuild and install.

Comment: @user1621969: you can also load timeSeries first, then PerformanceAnalytics.  That will ensure timeSeries and timeDate are further down the search path than xts/zoo, so the xts/zoo `time<-` methods will be found first.

Comment: Thanks to Brian for applying a patch quickly.  You can follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages) to checkout, build, and install the latest version of PerformanceAnalytics.