# Error generated from hydroplot in hydroTSM R package: no applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "zoo"

Tags: r, hydrotsm

I am trying use `hydroplot` from package `hydroTSM`, but i get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("time<-") : no applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "zoo"
```

I have used this code:

```
    td<-seq(as.Date("2009/02/12"), as.Date("2013/07/11"), "days") 
    Tempzoo = zoo(x=Temp, order.by=td)

    hydroplot(Tempzoo, na.rm=TRUE, ptype="ts+boxplot+hist", pfreq="dma",                      
      var.type="Temperature", var.unit="units", main=NULL, xlab="Time", ylab="Temp",
      win.len1=0, win.len2=0, tick.tstep="auto", lab.tstep="auto", 
      lab.fmt=NULL, cex=0.3, cex.main=1.3, cex.lab=1.3, cex.axis=1.3, 
      col=c("blue", "lightblue", "lightblue"), stype="default", season.names=c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"), 
      h=NULL)
```

Below is a subset of my data set:

```
    2009-02-12 2009-02-13 2009-02-14 2009-02-15 2009-02-16 2009-02-17 2009-02-18 
      3.535849   3.505208   3.973958   4.398958   4.004167   4.175000   5.598958 
    2009-02-19 2009-02-20 2009-02-21 2009-02-22 2009-02-23 2009-02-24 2009-02-25 
      5.507292   5.245833   5.639583   5.988542   6.458333   6.567708   5.811458 
    2009-02-26 2009-02-27 2009-02-28 2009-03-01 2009-03-02 2009-03-03 2009-03-04 
      5.533333   5.976042   6.027083   6.112500   5.576042   5.176042   5.326042 
    2009-03-05 2009-03-06 2009-03-07 2009-03-08 2009-03-09 2009-03-10 2009-03-11 
      4.746875   4.485417   4.975000   4.960417   4.829167   4.942708   5.175000 
    2009-03-12 2009-03-13 2009-03-14 2009-03-15 2009-03-16 2009-03-17 2009-03-18 
      5.789583   6.137500   6.628125   6.755208   7.046875   6.864583   7.033333 
    2009-03-19 2009-03-20 2009-03-21 2009-03-22 2009-03-23 2009-03-24 2009-03-25 
      7.427083   7.191667   7.229167   6.740625   6.194792         NA   6.117708 
    2009-03-26 2009-03-27 2009-03-28 2009-03-29 2009-03-30 2009-03-31 2009-04-01 
      6.702083   6.268750         NA   5.797917   6.637500   7.918750   8.744792 
    2009-04-02 2009-04-03 2009-04-04 2009-04-05 2009-04-06 2009-04-07 2009-04-08 
            NA         NA         NA   7.330208   7.075000         NA         NA 
    2009-04-09 2009-04-10 2009-04-11 2009-04-12 2009-04-13 2009-04-14 2009-04-15 
            NA         NA         NA         NA   9.031250   8.687500   8.841667 
    2009-04-16 2009-04-17 2009-04-18 2009-04-19 2009-04-20 2009-04-21 2009-04-22 
      9.947917   8.946875   8.512500   9.478125         NA  10.075000         NA 
   2009-04-23 2009-04-24 2009-04-25 2009-04-26 2009-04-27 2009-04-28 2009-04-29 
            NA         NA   9.272917   9.511458         NA   9.295833   9.764583
```

Any ideas on how  to resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: [Search on SO for your error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+Error+in+UseMethod%28%22time%3C-%22%29+%3A+no+applicable+method+for+%27time%3C-%27+applied+to+an+object+of+class+%22zoo%22), try `detach('package:timeSeries')`, try `hydroplot` again. And next time, please make it easier for people that wish to help you by providing [example data in a convenient format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Thanks!

Comment: @Henrik: Sounds like your comments taken together qualify as an answer.

Comment: It's somewhat ironic that the "possible" duplicate was closed because it was thought unlikely to help future readers, and here we have an instance where the future user might get help and the answer appears useful. I also think the original could be improved to unload a namespace correctly, but you obviously cannot go back and fix ... because it's closed. No one should dare to vote to close now!

Comment: @DWin, since I am not `detach`ing on a regular basis, please suggest an edit in my post on how to "unload a namespace correctly". In my answer I just used the first `?detach` example as template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [searched SO for your error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+Error+in+UseMethod%28%22time%3C-%22%29+%3A+no+applicable+method+for+%27time%3C-%27+applied+to+an+object+of+class+%22zoo%22), and tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105396/no-applicable-method-for-time-applied-to-an-object-of-class-cxts-zoo) provided by @Roland. And yes, it seems like package `timeSeries` was loaded when you tried to plot. Here is an example:

```
library(zoo)
library(hydroTSM)

# create data
td <- seq(as.Date("2009/02/12"), as.Date("2013/07/11"), "days") 
n <- length(td)
Temp <- sample(c(rnorm(n, mean = 10), rep(NA, n/5)), n)
Tempzoo <- zoo(x = Temp, order.by = td)


# in addition, load the suspected package ‘timeSeries’ 
library(timeSeries)
# Attaching package: ‘timeSeries’
# 
# The following object is masked from ‘package:zoo’:
#   
#   time<-

# try plot
hydroplot(x = Tempzoo,
          na.rm = TRUE,
          ptype = "ts+boxplot+hist",
          pfreq = "dma",                      
          var.type = "Temperature",
          var.unit = "units",
          main = NULL,
          xlab = "Time", ylab = "Temp",
          win.len1 = 0, win.len2 = 0,
          tick.tstep = "auto", lab.tstep = "auto", 
          lab.fmt = NULL,
          cex = 0.3, cex.main = 1.3, cex.lab = 1.3, cex.axis = 1.3, 
          col=c("blue", "lightblue", "lightblue"), stype="default",
          season.names = c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Autumn"), 
          h=NULL)

# Error in UseMethod("time<-") : 
#   no applicable method for 'time<-' applied to an object of class "zoo"

# i.e. your error

# detach ‘timeSeries’ 
detach(package:timeSeries)

# plot again
```

[image]

Comment: My understanding is that `unloadNamespace(ns)` is safer than `detach`. It also will detach the namespace.