# R Blotter demo not working under linux

Tags: r, demo, blotter

I am looking to run  the r blotter demo program under linux, and get the following error when I run demo(amzn_test)

```
> # update the portfolio stats
> updatePortf("amzn_port",Dates="2010-01-14")
Error in if (nzchar(intervals[1])) s <- as.POSIXlt(do.call(firstof, parse.side(intervals[1]))) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Interestingly, with the same version of R, everything runs fine in Windows. I am pretty new to R and hit a wall trying to trouble shoot. I did check the sessioInfo in Linux and Windows and they were a match except for the locale which I believe is OS specific.

On Linux:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-6          blotter_0.8.10          FinancialInstrument_1.0 quantmod_0.3-17         TTR_0.21-1              Defaults_1.1-1         
[7] xts_0.8-6               zoo_1.7-7              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.1  tools_2.15.1
```

On Windows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: I'll patch.  In the mean time, it will work with revision 1131.  So you can check out that revision if you are impatient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been patched in Rev. 1133.  The code was using the `time` function on a list instead of on an xts object that the list contained. It looks like this has been a problem for a while, but until a change yesterday to explicitly use `xts:::time.xts`, a different `time` method was being dispatched which happily returned different values than intended without error.  Thanks for the report.

If you need help checking out, building and installing the latest version, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105132/967840)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. With the latest version the first demo works, but the other 2 demos still dont. As with the first demo, they work on Windows. the error I am getting is `> # Create trades
> for( i in 10:NROW(GSPC) ) { 
+     # browser()
+     CurrentDate=time(GSPC)[i]
+     cat(".")
+     equity = getEndEq(ltaccount, C .... [TRUNCATED] 
.
Error in inherits(TF, "try-error") : object 'TF' not found
In addition: There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Brand new on SO, so not enough rep to upvote!!