# merged xts object are not aligned

Tags: r, xts

please, try the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY', from = '1950-01-01')
SPY <- to.monthly(SPY)
temp <- xts(Cl(SPY), index(SPY))
```

You will obtain a `xts` object which has the same length of `Cl(SPY)` and the same dates... or it **should be** so.

If you input

```
merge(Cl(SPY), temp)
```

you will see that, although `Cl(SPY)` and `temp` have the same index date, they are not aligned, the code produces doubles and a lot of `NA`s.

How may I merge them in a correct way?

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed in xts on R-Forge.  Please see [Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages) if you have issues installing xts from R-Forge.

```
install.packages("xts", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")

library(quantmod)
getSymbols('SPY', from = '1950-01-01')
SPY <- to.monthly(SPY)
temp <- xts(Cl(SPY), index(SPY))
merge(Cl(SPY),temp)
```

Comment: +1. Updating is the best solution, but a work-around would be to use `drop.time=TRUE`.  i.e. `SPY <- to.monthly(SPY, drop.time=TRUE)`