# Downloading Package "Cart" in R

Tags: r, package, cartogram

Does anybody know where I can download the R package "cart" that can help create Gastner's 
"Mapping with Diffusion-based Cartograms" ? I tried a install.package on R and says it's not available
for R 2.15. There is a page on R-forge about it but it doesn't explain how to download the package.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11105131/324364) may perhaps contain the answer...?

Answer (score 1):

Way late to the game, but from what I can tell there's [not much happening](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=package+cart+r+newman) for the `cart` package; my recent efforts with cartogramming in R have pushed me towards two alternatives: `Rcartogram` within R (available from the [GitHub](https://github.com/omegahat/Rcartogram) repository) and [ScapeToad](http://scapetoad.choros.ch/), a program written in JS.

Advantage of the former is that you don't have to leave R (better for long-term project management), however it's a bit arcane to use (requires converting your shapefile to a density grid & then figuring out how to use an interpolation method, etc.).

Advantage of the latter is that it's got a very simple point-and-click GUI--add shapefile, create cartogram wizard, export shapefile, *voila*.

Both are based on the [Gastner-Newman diffusion-based algorithm](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/20/7499.abstract).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [build page](http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=901) you'll see that at the moment the package fails to build.  I thought it might be something minor but I've put in a little bit of work so far and it's still failing to build on my machine.

You might want to email the authors and ask them.  You could also try [their forum](http://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/?group_id=901) but it looks like it hasn't seen much activity lately.