# Download VIX futures prices from CBOE

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to get historical prices for VIX futures by downloading all the CSV files on this page (http://cfe.cboe.com/Products/historicalVIX.aspx).  Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
library(XML)

#Extract all links for url
url <- "http://cfe.cboe.com/Products/historicalVIX.aspx"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
free(doc)

#Filter out URLs ending with csv and complete the link.
links <- links[substr(links, nchar(links) - 2, nchar(links)) == "csv"]
links <- paste("http://cfe.cboe.com", links, sep="")

#Peform read.csv on each url in links, skipping the first two URLs as they are not relevant.
c <- lapply(links[-(1:2)], read.csv, header = TRUE)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Upon further investigation, I realize this is because some of the CSV files are formatted differently.  If I load the URL `links[9]` manually, I see that the first row has this disclaimer:

```
CFE data is compiled for the .......use of CFE data is subject to the Terms and Conditions of CBOE's Websites.
```

Most of the other files (e.g.`links[8]` and `links[10]`) are fine so it seems this has been randomly inserted.  Is there some R magic that can be done to handle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a `getSymbols.cfe` method in my [**qmao**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) package (for the [`getSymbols`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/quantmod/docs/getSymbols) function in [**quantmod**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=quantmod) package) that will make this a lot easier.

```
#install.packages('qmao', repos='http://r-forge.r-project.org')
library(qmao)
```

This is from the examples section of `?getSymbols.cfe` (please read the help page as the function has a few arguments that you may want to be different than the defaults)

```
getSymbols(c("VX_U11", "VX_V11"),src='cfe') 
#all contracts expiring in 2010 and 2011.
getSymbols("VX",Months=1:12,Years=2010:2011,src='cfe')
#getSymbols("VX",Months=1:12,Years=10:11,src='cfe') #same
```

And it's not just for VIX

```
getSymbols(c("VM","GV"),src='cfe') #The mini-VIX and Gold vol contracts expiring this month
```

If you're not familiar with `getSymbols`, by default it stores the data in your `.GlobalEnv` and return the name of the object that was saved.

```
> getSymbols("VX_Z12", src='cfe')
[1] "VX_Z12"

> tail(VX_Z12)
           VX_Z12.Open VX_Z12.High VX_Z12.Low VX_Z12.Close VX_Z12.Settle VX_Z12.Change VX_Z12.Volume VX_Z12.EFP VX_Z12.OpInt
2012-10-26       19.20       19.35      18.62        18.87          18.9           0.0         22043         15        71114
2012-10-31       18.55       19.50      18.51        19.46          19.5           0.6         46405        319        89674
2012-11-01       19.35       19.35      17.75        17.87          17.9          -1.6         40609       2046        95720
2012-11-02       17.90       18.65      17.55        18.57          18.6           0.7         42592       1155       100691
2012-11-05       18.60       20.15      18.43        18.86          18.9           0.3         28136        110       102746
2012-11-06       18.70       18.85      17.75        18.06          18.1          -0.8         35599        851       110638
```

---

**Edit**

I see now that I did not answer your question, but rather pointed you to another way to get the same error!  A simple way to make your code work, is to make a wrapper for `read.csv` that uses `readLines` to see if the first row contains the disclaimer; if it does, skip the the first row, otherwise use `read.csv` as normal.

```
myRead.csv <- function(x, ...) {  
  if (grepl("Terms and Conditions", readLines(x, 1))) { #is the first row the disclaimer?
    read.csv(x, skip=1, ...)  
  } else read.csv(x, ...)
}
L <- lapply(links[-(1:2)], myRead.csv, header = TRUE)
```

I also applied that patch to `getSymbols.cfe`.  You can get the latest version of qmao (1.3.11) using svn checkout (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages) if you need help with that), or, you can wait until R-Forge builds it for you which usually happens pretty quickly, but could take up to a couple of days.

Comment: Thanks for that.  No need for me to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that VX_N13 has a disclaimer on the first row.  I will try to patch to deal with that soon.

Comment: @GSee Is there something like getQuote.cfe available. I am looking around and can not find it. I am asking since using getSmbols.cfe provides data that comes a bit to late "PLEASE NOTE: CFE Data does not become available until approximately 10:00 a.m. C.T. the following business day." The question is where to get (near) real time data. One obvious place for me is Interactive Brokers... Any other ideas (google, yahoo, ...)? Thnx.