# How to download historical data using R?

Tags: r, trading

I am looking for a package to download historical data of **Futures** (*NO STOCK DATA*).

could someone advice me some good R package?

Thanks!

P.S. I Know there are many packages, but they only seem to retrive stock prices, and not Futures. I Only need futures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282094/download-vix-futures-prices-from-cboe related question. I'm not aware of a specific package that lets you download, but you can get them from raw sources.

Comment: @Downvoter It's courteous to identify the reason you downvoted the question.

Comment: This is off-topic. Even if it weren't, you've got to be a lot more specific than "futures".  There are dozens of futures exchanges.  Most of them charge for data.

Comment: Here, I spent more time than warranted answering a similar question yesterday: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2013q1/011417.html.  In short, some exchanges, like SGX, provide time and sales data free.  For other ones, you have to pay.  Interactive Brokers is a cheap source.

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no free source of futures data. Atleast not comprehensive.

You can look into 'FinancialInstruments` package's source on R-Forge especially this file

https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/FinancialInstrument/inst/parser/download.tblox.R?view=markup&root=blotter

It will download historical data for select futures which [TradingBlox](http://www.tradingblox.com) publishes daily. Mind you this data is back adjusted continuous contract data and is created using TradingBlox's own methodology of back adjusting.

Among paid sources, [CSI data](http://www.csidata.com/) is reasonably priced for smaller traders and can give data in multiple formats and allows you to customize back adjustment logic.

There is interesting project [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/futures) but I really haven't seen it mentioned around much or tested accuracy of the data.

Comment: There's also `getSymbols.cfe` from [qmao](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) to get daily historical VIX futures data... such a broad question...