# devtools/GitHub download error

Tags: r, github, devtools

As of today I can not use `devtools` to install a package from GitHub.  I don't know if the error lies in:

1. Me
2. devtools
3. GitHub

I'm using `install_github` as follows and get the following error:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("reports", "trinker")

## > library(devtools)
## > install_github("reports", "trinker")
## Installing github repo(s) reports/master from trinker
## Installing reports.zip from https://github.com/trinker/reports/archive/master.zip
## Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
##   transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
##
## TRIED WITH SECOND REPO:
##
## > install_github("acc.roxygen2", "trinker")
## Installing github repo(s) acc.roxygen2/master from trinker
## Installing acc.roxygen2.zip from https://github.com/trinker/acc.roxygen2/archive/master.zip
## Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
##   transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

I tried this with a second repo and get the same error.  I know that other [similar errors](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-tiny-rcurl-headache/) are related to security certificate.

Here's my github repo https://github.com/trinker/reports

I can't seem to download and install either.  I can install the [tar.gz](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/Errors/reports_0.1.3.tar.gz) file  produced by an R build though.

**Where is the error occurring and why is it occurring?**

PS I can install for other people's github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("findPackage", "Dasonk")
```

**EDIT**

I can install my own qdap as well:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("qdap", "trinker")
```

Comment: (+1) For installing the most useful package ever.  findPackage has saved my life on numerous occasions.

Comment: I chose that one because I knew it didn't already reside in my Library :)

Comment: Is SO really the best place for this?  Every time a webpage changes its format, should we ask on SO how to fix code that scrapes it?

Comment: @GSee I can appreciate your sentiment but this is just any webpage.  This is a heavily relied upon R coding webpage (and many other languages).  This isn't a baseball stats page or fantasy football.  It also isn't just any code that scrapes, it's a heavily relied upon package.

Comment: As stated above I don't know the location of the problem.  See this [heavily upvoted similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages)

Comment: @GSee not sure what web scraping has to do with this question

Comment: @hadley, s/scraping/downloading.  Looks like I was wrong about it though.  Now that we know it's a github issue, I've voted to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with your repo.  `install_github` grabs the .zip file associated with your repository.  For some reason yours seems to be an empty .zip file so clearly it can't install.

The [tarball](https://github.com/trinker/reports/archive/master.tar.gz) doesn't seem to be empty.  My guess is that it's just a hiccup in github that should go away with time.

Comment: OK Dason I'll wait and see.  Any ideas on how to force the .zip to update?  I tried adding to the read me and pushing to github but no dice.

Comment: Because it appears to be a github issue I contacted them for help and will report back here the response.

Comment: @TylerRinker I have no idea how to force it to update.  If I had to guess though I would say that if you stopped being such a horrible raptor that would fix the problem.

Comment: For future searchers [this site](https://status.github.com/) is where you'd go first if github seems to be not working correctly.