# Push to Github Stuck on Rstudio

Tags: r, github, rstudio

While I am trying to push on GitHUb from rstudio it is stuck and is not reflecting on Github
There might be some mismatch in the settings that I have configured watching tutorials.

Error Screenshot

[image]

Git Settings

[image]

Rstudio Options

[image]

GitHub Account Settings

[image]

Repository Settings

[image]

Comment: I don't see any errors in your error screenshot

Comment: It just doesn't upload anything to the github

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while following one of the courses online. I don't know exactly what causes this issue.

Problem: Exactly the same with every setting as shown in the screenshot.

The solution:

- in RStudio, click on the "Tools" menu and select "Shell"
- Run the following command: git push
- it might ask you for your git username and password. Supply this
  information, make sure it is correct
- hopefully, the push is successful, then you can close the window
- Now make some more edits to some files so that you have new content to
  push
- Click on the "push" button in RStudio and this time the push should
  work

This is not my solution I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45804117/5677883

Comment: Please do not copy answers. If you believe the question is a duplicate, please flag it or suggest it in the question comments.