# install_github downloads blank master.zip

Tags: r, github

I have put a test R project on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/HamiltonBlake/test)), and am trying to install using the following:

```
devtools::install_github('HamiltonBlake/test')
```

I get the following output:

```
Installing github repo test/master from HamiltonBlake
Downloading test.zip from https://github.com/HamiltonBlake/test/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\Ham\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAzTLDT/test.zip
Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

If I manually go to https://github.com/HamiltonBlake/test/archive/master.zip and download it, it's a zipped folder with server.R and ui.R as expected.

However when I go to my Temp folder, the zipped folder which has been downloaded above contains an empty file called "file236447a6420", and an empty folder called "rs-graphics-3f4820b1-7366-461a-b095-f2106ef72e73".

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282003/devtools-github-download-error) which made it look like it's a matter of waiting a few hours, however unlike this question, I can download and install from the same path that install_github uses, so it looks like github has already updated the master.zip.

I have full read/write access on my PC, and the latest devtools and rtools.

Comment: To use `install_github` you can't just put any R code on github.  It must be in the form of an R package.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of `install_github` says

```
Attempts to install a package directly from github.
```

If you have ui.R and server.R that implies you actually have a shiny app - not a package.

You'll want to look into the `runGitHub` function in the shiny package if you want to run directly from github or you can clone the repository locally and use `runApp`.

Comment: Good find and also I must say that is a very classy dog +1 mostly for the classy dog.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great find.