# How to get market sector for a given stock ticker in R?

Tags: r, quantmod, stock

I am currently trying to get the market sector for any given stock ticker

```
For example, 

AAPL - Technology 
XOM - Energy
```

I have tried the following from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432512/find-which-sector-a-stock-belongs-to) and received these errors.

```
#Attempt to intsall qamo
    install.packages("qmao", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
    library(qmao)
    install.packages('RJSONIO')
    library(RJSONIO)
    install.packages('pander')
    library(pander)
    spyh <- getHoldings("SPY", auto.assign=FALSE)
    head(ss[ss$Symbol %in% rownames(spyh), ])
    
    error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
        In addition: Warning message:
        In file(file, "rt") :
          cannot open URL 'http://www.masterdata.com/helpfiles/ETF_List_Downloads/AllTypes.csv': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

#Install & Use TTR
library(TTR)
ss <- stockSymbols()
error: Fetching AMEX symbols...
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
```

Comment: In the new version of TTR, `stockSymbols()` no longer returns the sectors, because it uses the FTP file.  As you can see, the prior method no longer works.

Comment: thanks @joshuaUlrich I appreciate all the work you and your team does. You all are amazing