# Error installing packages from github

Tags: r, github

I can't install packages from github:

```
> install_github('cranvas', 'ggobi', args="--no-multiarch")
Installing github repo(s) cranvas/master from ggobi
Installing cranvas.zip from https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/archive/master.zip
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
```

this is my session:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

NB: `install.packages` works as usual, it's just with github the issue. Have some of you ever faced this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using/behind some proxy? Check if you can download it with a browser or `wget https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Yes I am and I can confirm the terminal can't get the url. I thought is wasn't a problem since I can use install from cran and I was also able to download the master.zip from mozilla (and then unzip and re zip as tar.gz to install).

Comment: What about `install_url("http://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/archive/master.zip", "cranvas")`?

Comment: @Salem same result unfortunately

Comment: @Hadley I'm also getting the same error. I've hunted around and tried quite a few things including `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` but no luck so far. Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from : http://healthvis.org/install/

Some users have run into the following error when using the instructions above: Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : couldn't connect to host. This is likely due to the use of proxies (which would prevent you from installing any package from github), and can be rectified using the httr package. Run the following commands before install_github(...) above:

```
install.packages("httr")
library(devtools)
library(httr)
set_config(use_proxy(url="http://proxyname.company.com",port=8080,username="XXX",password="XXX")) 
install_github("cranvas")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I used this and it worked for me

```
    library(downloader)
    download("https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/archive/master.tar.gz", "plotly.tar.gz")
    install.packages("plotly.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Answer (score 2):

GitHub no longer supports HTTP. That was disabled quite some years ago and it may have been aligned with [mitigation of FireSheep](https://github.com/blog/737-sidejack-prevention).  My test was as follows:

```
curl -i http://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/archive/master.zip
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Mon, 26 Aug 2013 03:15:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
Location: https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/archive/master.zip
Vary: Accept-Encoding

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the 301 and HTTPS as the replacement URL.