# How to use install_github

Tags: r, curl, github, package

I am trying to calculate weight of evidence and information value, and found online that R package `riv` and `tomasgreif` does the job. Both packages are located on github, so I used the following code:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("riv","tomasgreif")
library(woe)
```

But it gives me the following error/warning message:

```
> install_github("riv","tomasgreif")
Installing github repo riv/master from tomasgreif
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/tomasgreif/riv/archive/master.zip
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host
In addition: Warning message:
In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
  Unrecognized CURL options: writedata
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to download the file manually. R returned no error, but the package is not found in the list... (I am able to install some other packages saved in the same location with similar code)

```
> install.packages("~/riv.zip", repos = NULL)
> library("riv")
Error in library("riv") : there is no package called ‘riv’
```

Comment: The `install_github` command works fine for me. If it isn't a temporary error (have you tried again?), perhaps the problem is related to a network problem and not R. Can you download the master.zip file manually in a browser?

Comment: Have you considered it being due to a proxy, similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740256/error-installing-packages-from-github

Comment: Yes I do think it is due to a proxy, but I can't figure out how the proxy works. And I've updated my question with the problem I had trying to download the file to local drive. @r2evans

Comment: The package is called "riv-master" but the DESCRIPTION file calls it "woe", so try `library(woe)` instead.

Comment: same error... `Error in library(woe) : there is no package called ‘woe’`

Comment: When I downloaded the file it was named `riv-master.zip` (from what `install_github` tried) so I'm not certain what zip file you downloaded.

Comment: Yes, that is the same as what I got.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it via downloading Open Source R from Revolution Analytics, then manually downloaded woe package from git and pasting that directly into library folder of OpenSource R
and loaded it library(woe) it will work

Also based on the same lines will be releasing IV and WOE for python also