# What to do when a package is not available for our R version?

Tags: r

Very often, when I try to download a package, I've got the following message :

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XXXX’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Is it not possible to simulate an old version of R to use the package ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11105131/271616

Comment: I believe you also get this message when the package is on Bioconductor (Bioconductor.org).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/752843) would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like:

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/XXXX/XXXX_A.B.C.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, contriburl=NULL, type="source")
```

where `XXXX` is your package name and `A.B.C` is the version of the package (not R).

Comment: How do you find the package version needed to install on a version of R?

Comment: @highBandWidth, there is a label usually on CRAN, eg. 'Package source: ' and then below ' Old sources: ' which if you click it, gives you the list of the previous versions from the most recent. If the error messages don't direct you, some trial and error may be necessary. I do not know of a precise way to identify the A.B.C version correspondence for each package with the R version