# package ‘diamonds’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)

Tags: r, package

what is the easy way to have diamonds package/dataset in my R environment. I am newbie using RStudio (3.0)

```
> install.packages("diamonds")
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘diamonds’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘diamonds’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)
```

I donot want to download and rebuild R as discussed in the following thread
[Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages)

Comment: If you get this error message, it is a good idea to check if the package really exists on CRAN.  You can do this by visiting the website.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `diamonds` data set is actually part of the excellent `ggplot2` package (incidentally, you can find this out with `??diamonds`).  The following should get you started:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library('ggplot2')
diamonds
```