# Adjusting for Stock Splits in R Error?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, stockquotes

I have an intraday dataset with closing prices that I want to adjust stock prices for stock splits. I have found the `adjustOHLC()` from the `quantmod` package to work *almost* effectively.

Here is one of the many *UNADJUSTED* tickers in my dataset called: AGII

```
datset <- structure(c(52.15, 52.17, 52.135, 52.155, 52.1, 52.1, 52.23, 
52.145, 52.185, 52.15, 52.215, 52.185, 52.15, 52.32, 52.415, 
52.4, 52.41, 52.42, 52.51, 52.39, 52.42, 52.02, 52, 52.12, 52.12, 
52.15, 52.06, 52.13, 52.13, 52.02, 52.02, 52.12, 52.06, 52.06, 
52, 52.025, 51.97, 51.96, 52.02, 52, 52.005, 52, 52.09, 52.17, 
52.15, 52.47, 52.51, 52.76, 52.58, 52.73, 52.65, 52.75, 52.7295, 
52.56, 52.5, 52.5, 52.46, 52.43, 52.3, 52.467, 52.48, 52.48, 
52.53, 52.657, 52.633, 52.55, 52.565, 52.56, 52.57, 52.735, 52.71, 
52.72, 52.55, 52.55, 52.34, 52.54, 52.46, 52.54, 52.45, 52.74, 
52.67, 52.8, 52.61, 52.63, 52.74, 52.78, 52.78, 52.59, 52.79, 
52.81, 52.81, 52.725, 52.69, 52.6, 52.675, 52.58, 52.67, 52.67, 
47.63, 47.57, 47.59, 47.57, 47.73, 47.64, 47.64, 47.64, 47.75, 
47.74, 47.78, 47.78, 47.83, 47.86, 47.99, 47.94, 47.94, 48, 47.97, 
47.97, 48.01, 47.88, 47.86, 47.96, 47.93, 47.98, 47.98, 48.06, 
48.01, 47.96, 47.93, 47.93, 48.02, 48.01, 48.04, 48.06, 48.12, 
48.1599, 48.1599, 48.18, 48.15, 48.19, 48.16, 48.11, 48.115, 
48.1, 48.08, 48.07, 48.04, 48.02, 47.995, 47.91), .indexTZ = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "", index = structure(c(1424481300, 1424482200, 
1424483100, 1424484000, 1424484900, 1424485800, 1424486700, 1424487600, 
1424488500, 1424489400, 1424490300, 1424491200, 1424492100, 1424493000, 
1424493900, 1424494800, 1424495700, 1424496600, 1424497500, 1424498400, 
1424735100, 1424736000, 1424736900, 1424737800, 1424738700, 1424739600, 
1424740500, 1424741400, 1424742300, 1424743200, 1424744100, 1424745000, 
1424745900, 1424746800, 1424747700, 1424748600, 1424749500, 1424750400, 
1424751300, 1424752200, 1424753100, 1424754000, 1424754900, 1424755800, 
1424756700, 1424757600, 1424821500, 1424822400, 1424823300, 1424824200, 
1424825100, 1424826000, 1424826900, 1424827800, 1424828700, 1424829600, 
1424830500, 1424831400, 1424832300, 1424833200, 1424834100, 1424835000, 
1424835900, 1424836800, 1424837700, 1424838600, 1424839500, 1424840400, 
1424841300, 1424842200, 1424843100, 1424844000, 1424907900, 1424908800, 
1424909700, 1424910600, 1424911500, 1424912400, 1424913300, 1424914200, 
1424915100, 1424916000, 1424916900, 1424917800, 1424918700, 1424919600, 
1424920500, 1424921400, 1424922300, 1424923200, 1424924100, 1424925000, 
1424925900, 1424926800, 1424927700, 1424928600, 1424929500, 1424930400, 
1424994300, 1424995200, 1424996100, 1424997000, 1424997900, 1424998800, 
1424999700, 1425000600, 1425001500, 1425002400, 1425003300, 1425004200, 
1425005100, 1425006000, 1425006900, 1425007800, 1425008700, 1425009600, 
1425010500, 1425011400, 1425012300, 1425013200, 1425014100, 1425015000, 
1425015900, 1425016800, 1425080700, 1425081600, 1425082500, 1425083400, 
1425084300, 1425085200, 1425086100, 1425087000, 1425087900, 1425088800, 
1425089700, 1425090600, 1425091500, 1425092400, 1425093300, 1425094200, 
1425095100, 1425096000, 1425096900, 1425097800, 1425098700, 1425099600, 
1425100500, 1425101400, 1425102300, 1425103200), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(150L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "AGII"))
```

If you plot it, you will see the big drop in price i need to adjust for:

```
library(quantmod)
chartSeries(datset$AGII)
```

Since this is part of a larger dataset & I need to adjust many tickers I have written the following loop:

```
library(quantmod)
dataset <- xts()
NOMS <- names(datset)

for(i in 1:length(NOMS)) {
  NOMS[i]-> symbol
  # Symbol might not be found so I try "skip" the ticker with "try()"
  tryit <- try(adjustOHLC(to.period(datset[,symbol],"minutes",15), adjust=c("split"), symbol.name=symbol))
  if(inherits(tryit, "try-error")){
    ADJ = datset[,symbol]
    colnames(ADJ)<- symbol
    dataset <- merge.xts(dataset,ADJ)
  } else {
    # If ticker is found, then adjust it
    ADJ = adjustOHLC(to.period(datset[,symbol],"minutes",15), adjust=c("split"), symbol.name=symbol)
    ADJ <- Cl(ADJ)
    colnames(ADJ)<- symbol
    dataset <- merge.xts(dataset,ADJ)
  }
}
```

Now if you plot it: `chartSeries(dataset)` ... it is overstated February 24. The actual stock split occurs February 26 (if that helps)

```
   # To see split factor & when it occured
    getSplits("AGII",from="2015-02-20")
```

How do I get the appropriate split without it being overstated?

Comment: Here's a function that does a yahoo-style dividend/split adjustment on intraday data: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/adjustIntraday.yahoo.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument

Comment: @GSee thanks the function is excellent!

Comment: @GSee Is the `qmao` package compatible with mac osx Yosemite & the  R version 3.1.2 ? I have tried `install.packages("qmao")` & also `install.packages("~/Desktop/R/qmao_1.6.10.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source") ` with no luck...  :(

Comment: Yes, but it's not on CRAN, so you'd need to use `install.packages("qmao", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")` or `devtools::install_github("gsee/qmao")` or you could [checkout/build/install from source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages/11105132#11105132).  (qmao has quite a few dependencies that you need to install first)

Comment: @GSee thanks I was now able to install `qmao` but I needed to load gdata, shiny, and pander first... qmao is awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, these functions were designed to work on daily data, not intraday data.

Second, the problem is that `Date` objects are considered to be at midnight UTC, and your `datset` object has no timezone.  So the adjustment algorithm thinks the split occurred at whatever midnight UTC happens to be in your system's timezone.

The work-around is to do this yourself, after adjusting the timezone of the split data to be the same as your local timezone.

```
s <- getSplits(symbol)
indexTZ(s) <- indexTZ(x)       # ensure the objects have the same timezone
index(s) <- index(s)           # force an index recalculation
indexClass(s) <- "POSIXct"     # convert index to POSIXct
r <- adjRatios(s, NA, datset)  # calculate adjustment ratios
y <- adjustOHLC(x, ratio=r$Split, symbol.name=symbol)
chartSeries(Cl(y))
```

Notice that you still see a spike in the adjusted data, because the split likely did not apply at midnight on 2015-02-26. You can work around that by lagging the adjustment ratios.

```
r2 <- na.locf(lag(r), fromLast=TRUE)
y2 <- adjustOHLC(x, ratio=r2$Split, symbol.name=symbol)
chartSeries(Cl(y2))
```