# Difficulty Installing CHAID Package

Tags: r

I am trying to install a CHAID Package using the below code. But I am getting a warning as 'CHAID' is not available. I even installed "partykit" as an additional supporting package. can someone please help me with this?

install.packages("CHAID", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘CHAID’ is not available (for R version 3.1.3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages

Comment: Hard to tell. That code worked fine on my machine. Now what do you suppose might be different about our machines. eh?

Comment: Have now tried this on R 3.1.3 also, and it works. You should show us your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: it worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the package "partykit" first.