# stack imbalance in DEoptim

Tags: r

I'm trying to use DEoptim but I'm getting this error, following [this instructions](http://www.rinfinance.com/RinFinance2009/presentations/yollin_slides.pdf):

```
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 13 then 12
Warning: stack imbalance in '<-', 11 then 10
```

This is my code

```
optOmega = function(x,ret,L)
{
  retu = ret %*% x
  obj = -Omega(retu,L=L,method="simple")
  weight.penalty = 100*(1-sum(x))^2
  return( obj + weight.penalty )
}
n.assets = 10
wmax = 1
lower = rep(0,n.assets)
upper = rep(wmax,n.assets)

r<- c(.1,.3,.4,.3,.02,.4,.7,.24,.3,.4)
r<-.5
res = DEoptim(optOmega,lower,upper,
              control=list(NP=2000,itermax=1000,F=0.2,CR=0.8),
              ret=coredata(r),L=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the sources from R-Forge, which have this fixed:

http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=773

And you can build using these instructions [Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages)  (changing where appropriate to DEoptim instead of returnanalytics)

Comment: Can you explain a little more instead of providing just links. It is advised to add as much as information you can in your answer because links may be removed or may not wok due to some reasons.

Comment: @VicJordan: the first link is to the source code. The second is to another StackOverflow question.  I'm not sure what you want them to include in their answer...