# Cant install blotter package used for quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I'm trying to use the `quantstrat` package in R. I have uploaded/installed the package using

```
install.packages("quantstrat", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

However the once I use

```
require(quanstrat)
```

I get the message :

> Loading required package: quantstrat
>   Failed with error:  ‘package ‘blotter’ required by ‘quantstrat’ could not be found’

I then use

```
install.packages("blotter", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

but get the following message:

> Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
>     ‘blotter’
>     These will not be installed

Can anyone offer some suggestion?

Comment: Well, if the error message says it's only avaialblein source form, install the source form. `install.packages("blotter", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")`

Comment: tried that MrFlick , but now i get the following result?

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘blotter’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)

Comment: If you are using Windows, you probably need to install [Rtools](http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) first.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but now get the following eror message:

Comment: Related: [Cannot install R-forge package using install.packages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11105131/271616)

Comment: My problem seems to have been a windows vs R version compatibility issue. Ive reinstalled an older version of R (3.1.3) and everythings is now working. THanks to everyone for all the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late here, but perhaps relevant to note that "blotter" and "quantstrat" are not on CRAN, and several years ago moved to GitHub. The README on the repo (https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat) has more information for installing blotter and more importantly quantstrat.

```
install.packages("devtools") # if not installed
install.packages("FinancialInstrument") #if not installed
install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics") #if not installed

# next install blotter from GitHub
devtools::install_github("braverock/blotter")
# next install quantstrat from GitHub
devtools::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

Comment: Please don't leave the same answer on multiple duplicate questions. Leave one answer, and flag the rest of the questions for being duplicates.