# install.packages + type="source" and R CMD INSTALL --build fail to install PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I tried to install the latest version of `PerformanceAnalytics` using two methods suggested in [a well answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105131/cannot-install-r-forge-package-using-install-packages/26274072#26274072) by @GSee and @hadley.

I have no idea where went wrong. Could anyone have a loot at it?

The first method I tried is using the following code:

```
install.packages("/Users/Natsume/Downloads/R packages/PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.4000.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I got the following error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ ...
** libs
gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  momentF.f90 -o momentF.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [momentF.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/PerformanceAnalytics’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/PerformanceAnalytics’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/Natsume/Downloads/R packages/PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.4000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

The second method I tried is following @GSee's method exactly, but error occured when I ran the following code:

```
R --vanilla CMD INSTALL --build returnanalytics/pkg/PerformanceAnalyt
```

Here is the error message:

```
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ ...
** libs
gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  momentF.f90 -o momentF.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [momentF.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/PerformanceAnalytics’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/PerformanceAnalytics’
```

Comment: The error seems to be unrelated to the package. Apparently the system does not find the fortran compiler. If you are using a Linux system, you could try to install the compiler with `sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.8` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You need to be able to install compiled code from source.  See [Section 6.3.2 OS X in R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#OS-X-packages) and [Appendix C.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#OS-X).  I don't use a Mac, so I'm not much help beyond pointing to the relevant docs...

Comment: We recently added / expanded entries in the [Rcpp FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) that deal with the same issue -- one needs `gfortran` to use RcppArmadillo and its LAPACK libraries for linking (even though we don't directly include Fortran). The toolchain is the same so these two entries and links there should help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful replies. I don't know how I got it done, so I wrote down what I did in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ Dirk Eddelbuettel, @Joshua Ulrich, @RHertel for your helpful replies.

I tried a bunch of things, some of them did not go through completely. I am not sure which one worked. but this is what I did:

- run these two lines

`curl -O    http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2`
 `sudo    tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /`

- However, I remembered at this point I was able to install `PerformanceAnalytics` but `library(PerformanceAnalytics)` caused errors. And I am not sure my mac successfully ran through those two lines. So, I went to download gfortran4.8 from elsewhere.
- install gfortran4.8 from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries)
- install gfortran 5 from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries)
- However, something was still not right. I guessed maybe I should uninstall gfortran4.8, so I ran the following code:  `sudo rm -r /usr/local/gfortran /usr/local/bin/gfortran`

somehow, it seemed working. But apparently I have no idea which exactly helped me managed to get `install.packages` + `type="source"` on `PerformanceAnalytics` package done. Also, it produced a lot of warnings as follows:

```
> install.packages("/Users/Natsume/Downloads/R packages/PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.4000.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ ...
** libs
gfortran-4.8  -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  momentF.f90 -o momentF.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘15.4.0
momentF.f90:2.1:

 subroutine asVecCov1(ia, n, oa)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:8.1:

 implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:11.1:

 integer :: n
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:12.1:

 double precision :: ia(n), oa(n*n)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:15.1:

 integer :: i, j, ii
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:20.1:

 ii = 1
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:21.1:

 do j=1,n
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:22.1:

  do i=1,n
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:23.1:

   oa(ii) = ia(i) * ia(j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:24.1:

   ii = ii + 1
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:25.1:

  end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:26.1:

 end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:28.1:

 end subroutine asVecCov1
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:30.1:

 subroutine asVec(im, nr, nc, oa)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:38.1:

 implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:41.1:

 integer :: nr, nc
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:42.1:

 double precision :: im(nr,nc), oa(nr * nc)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:45.1:

 integer :: i, j
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:50.1:

 do j=1,nc
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:51.1:

  do i=1,nr
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:52.1:

   oa(i + (j-1) * nr) = im(i,j)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:53.1:

  end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:54.1:

 end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:56.1:

 end subroutine asVec
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:58.1:

 subroutine M3(x, mu, nr, nc, C, om)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:68.1:

 implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:71.1:

 integer :: nr, nc
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:72.1:

 double precision :: x(nr, nc), mu(nc), om(nc, nc*nc), C(nc*nc, nc)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:75.1:

 integer :: i
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:76.1:

 double precision :: alpha, beta
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:77.1:

 double precision :: centret(nc), tccr(nc * nc)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:79.1:

 alpha = 1.d0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:80.1:

 beta = 1.d0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:82.1:

 do i=1,nr
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:83.1:

  centret = x(i,:) - mu
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:86.1:

  call asVecCov1(centret, nc, tccr)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:94.1:

  call DGEMM('N', 'N', nc*nc, nc, 1, alpha, tccr, nc*nc, centret, 1, beta, C, n
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:95.1:

 end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:97.1:

 om = transpose(C) / DBLE(nr)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:120.1:

 end subroutine M3
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:122.1:

 subroutine M4(x, mu, nr, nc, D, om)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:132.1:

 implicit none
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:135.1:

 integer :: nr, nc
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:136.1:

 double precision :: x(nr, nc), mu(nc), om(nc, nc*nc*nc), D(nc*nc*nc, nc)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:139.1:

 integer :: i
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:140.1:

 double precision :: alpha, beta, beta1
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:141.1:

 double precision :: centret(nc), tccr(nc * nc), tccr2(nc * nc * nc), C(nc*nc, 
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:143.1:

 alpha = 1.d0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:144.1:

 beta = 0.d0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:145.1:

 beta1 = 1.d0
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:147.1:

 do i=1,nr
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:148.1:

  centret = x(i,:) - mu
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:152.1:

  call asVecCov1(centret, nc, tccr)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:159.1:

  call asVec(C, nc*nc, nc, tccr2)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:162.1:

  call DGEMM('N', 'N', nc*nc*nc, nc, 1, alpha, tccr2, nc*nc*nc, centret, 1, bet
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:163.1:

 end do
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:165.1:

 om = transpose(D) / DBLE(nr)
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
momentF.f90:188.1:

 end subroutine M4
 1
Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)
gfortran-4.8 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o PerformanceAnalytics.so momentF.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘15.4.0
ld: warning: object file (momentF.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.4)
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/PerformanceAnalytics/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (PerformanceAnalytics)
```