# R-Studio Fail To Install Packages

Tags: r, installation, repository, package

I am using R for time series,The SMA() function in the “TTR” R package would be used, but when I first install the “TTR” R package like

```
>install.packages("TTR")
Warning message:
package ‘TTR’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

Comment: Install from the source, as per [Getting TTR to work on R x.xx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751659/getting-ttr-to-work-on-r-2-13)

Comment: See the general tips about installing from the latest source, from a more up-to-date repo e.g. R-forge [How should I deal with “package 'xxx' is not available” warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue with that package not being available on CRAN as a binary package for your particular OS / R Version combination. In my experience when this happens you can do one of two things:

- you can install R 3.2.1 (which is the current version)
- you can install from source using

  install.packages("TTR", type="source")